# HElp for Https?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

i want to send request on Https  so do i need to install the SSL certificate as the steps are given for apple push notification

please help me i am new and i have never worked on OpenSSL

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install SSL certificate on the client.

To work with HTTPS, you only need the server certificate, generate the session-key and then use that key to do further encrypted communication.

Comment: gaurav can u be in touch and help me regarding this Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know about openSSL but can do it in Java / .Net etc :)